# Prevent user from adding mail account to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

We have a consultant who does work for us. We've issued him a laptop and a mail account (for our domain) and have configured it in Outlook 2007. We'd like to be able to prevent them from adding their own personal mail account to Outlook.

Aside from user education and just telling them not to do it; is there a technical solution that I can use to achieve this as well?

Comment: This can be controlled be a group policy.  This is a consultant, make it a beach of contract clause, so if it's discovered you can get rid of the individual and sue them for breaching the contract (put a monetary penalty on this clause).  I am dead serious about this suggestion by the way